# downloading file in Codename one

Tags: codenameone

hey i have been trying to use the Util.downloadUrlToFileSystemInBackground method but its not working.when i run the codename One simulator it gets stuck in a loop.what i would like is the download to work in the background ,plus i would also like to display a download progress.below is the code responsible for the download

```
    Map<String, String> data = myList.get(i);
               String link = data.get("fileurl");
                Util.downloadUrlToFileSystemInBackground(link,title,   new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                        try{
                            InputStream is = Storage.getInstance().createInputStream(link);
                            Media mm = MediaManager.createMedia(is, "audio/mp3");
                            mm.play();
                        }
                        catch (IOException ex) {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

You download the URL to a file named `title` then in the callback after the download completed you try to open a `Storage` file (which is **not** a file system file).

I'm guessing title isn't a valid file either...

This shouldn't get into a loop but it won't work. One obvious fix is to replace `downloadUrlToFileSystemInBackground` with `downloadUrlToStorageInBackground`.

Notice that `Storage` != `FileSystemStorage`.

Comment: is there any way i can display the background downloads in another form

Comment: Sure, I don't understand the problem?

Comment: with your help i have solved the problem and the download is working.my New question is i would like to display the download progress in another form.can you point me in the right direction

Comment: Sure just show that other form then show the download progress